# How to pass a JSON file in php curl POSTFILEDS parameters

Tags: curl

How do I pass a json File as data.json in `curl_setot($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, @data.json)`

such that the whole data.json file gets passed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the content from the file

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($file_data_json));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
```

If you want to send the file as upload:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("data.json" => $file_data_json));
```